# google maps api example load map not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have view this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=de) from google maps api developer site.

I will try to testing this example. But this not working and i don't know why this not working.

Here my HTML Code:

```
<div class="six columns padding_right_left_clean">
    <div class="responsiveContainer">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the JavaScript code from the example Page:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/97wFy/)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: what about including the api js in your html so you actualy have those variables?

Comment: I use the google maps api:http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places and the variable what i use is from the api js. I don't know why i can not see the map

Comment: Your map div doesn't have a size.

Comment: you mean that my id map-canvas have not height and width ?

Comment: Yes: http://jsfiddle.net/97wFy/3/ See [Mike Williams' description of percentage sizing in his v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm) if you want a "responsive" layout.

Comment: @geocodezip damn :) it work's and I took so long for find this solve. thx you

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>` into your code? 
You should find out Google Map API on this link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: be careful about css. May be you forgot <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
    </style>